# refer a question 'to the knowledgeable' or 'to knowledgeable' persons

Tags: definite-articles

Should I use 'THE' when saying that we should refer a certain question to knowledgeable people (or to the knowledgeable people)?

Comment: It depends. Have you mentioned knowledgeable people prior to the sentence? If not, and you use the definite article, then the immediate question is: *Which* knowledgeable people?

Comment: And what if I have not used the knowledgeable people prior to the sentence and do not use 'THE' what does it imply then?

Comment: That the question should be asked of (some) knowledgeable people. Just not a *particular* group of knowledgeable people.

Comment: If you don't mind, may I ask if you are originally from Canada and if English is your 1st language by birth (and the language of your elders)?

Comment: "_That the question should be asked of (some) knowledgeable people._" Can't it imply that the question should be asked of ALL knowledgeable people?

Comment: Not by any reasonable standard. No "sane" person would ever assume they could track down everyone who meets a certain standard of knowledgeability—and then ask them all. Even if you could identify every such person on the planet, you'd never get to them all. But if that's what's *really* meant, then then *all* or *every* should be added to the sentence to make it explicit.

Comment: Thank you. I have gotten my answer. If you can consolidate all your comments and put them as an answer here, I will be happy to accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to the question depends on if you've previously identified a group of knowledgeable people or not.

> I'm going to refer my question to **the** knowledgeable people.

With this statement, there are a couple of general responses.

> 1. What? *Which* knowledgeable people?

(If they have not yet been identfied.)

> 2. Oh, the ones in the hut over there. Let me know what they say.

(If it's been previously stated that some knowledgeable people live in a hut.)

Should none have been identified, then the definite article would normally be not be used.

> I'm going to refer my question to knowledgeable people.
>   Let me know what they say . . .

Of course, even with an indefinite article, somebody could ask to whom you are referring.

> I'm going to ask a knowledgeable person.
>   Really? Which one did you have in mind?

But in this case, the statement isn't as confusing to the respondent, and the clarifying question that follows is a natural extension of the dialogue rather than something asked out of puzzlement.

---

To address something else that came up in comments under the question, it's assumed that if you don't qualify the statement with something like **all** or **every** that you're only talking about **some** knowledgeable people—typically just one or a few.

It would be unreasonable to think that you could identify every knowledgeable person on the planet and somehow ask all of them your question.